# ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired AWSBIS308I End of job

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, ora-00054

I executed a script containing an Oracle Procedure but I had  this  error message:

> `ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired AWSBIS308I End of job`

Here is the part of procedure where the error is generated:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set workarea_size_policy=manual';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set hash_area_size=262144000';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set sort_area_size=209715200';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set nls_date_format = ''DD/MM/YYYY'' ';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set nls_numeric_characters = ''.,'' ';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session enable commit in procedure';
```

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball is broken. Therefore, could you please post the *complete* procedure, as well as the script calling the procedure?

Comment: @oualid `ORA-00054: resource busy` error is something related to `ALTER` or `SYNONYM` change to a locked DB object. Please let us know if you make any `DDL` changes to a table, in your *Procedure*

Comment: Thank you, I could resolve the problem, this error is caused because of running of two queries on the same time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842765/ora-00054-resource-busy-and-acquire-with-nowait-specified-or-timeout-expired)

Comment: Those are some evil-looking `alter session` commands.  Maybe it's time for a code review.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused when you run two modifying queries at the same time on the same table. See linked duplicate.