# ORA-00054 error when trying to delete table

Tags: sql, oracle

When I try this command on oracle sql-developer :

```
delete from my_table;
```

I get the following error :

> ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified

I haven't figured out how to solve this problem.

Comment: table has been locked by another transaction

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842765/ora-00054-resource-busy-and-acquire-with-nowait-specified-or-timeout-expired)

Answer (score 2):

Someone or yourself(unintentionally) has a lock on the table. 
Query the table `V$LOCKED_OBJECTS` to find the name of the user (you would want `OS_USER_NAME`) locking it.

You can ask the user to unlock the table. They will have to either commit/rollback their transaction. If they are unable to do so and permit you to kill their session, you can use the below:

```
alter system kill session 'sid, serial#'
```

to kill their session which has a lock on your table where '`sid`' & '`serial#`' is something you have to find by querying `v$session`,`v$sqlarea` tables.

This can also be done in SQL developer, you can find out the session (if your user has access to meta tables) from the menu `Tools --> Monitor Sessions`
Right click on the correct session record (very important) and select  mark for kill. You should be able to delete the records once the session is killed.

Comment: In an application deadlocks are a sign of poor design.  In SQL Developer perhaps it's just confused development practice.  In either case killing the blocking session should be a last resort (which is why it is a restricted privilege).

Comment: when i try to execute the query :  select * from V$LOCKED_OBJECTS; i get the "table or view does not exist" error...

Comment: @ArLi91 You'll have to ask your DBA / Sysadmin to do this for you. You seem to lack the necessary privileges to access the `V$LOCKED_OBJECTS` table

Comment: Just in case anyone struggles with this, it's  v$locked_object (singular), not  v$locked_objects (plural)

Answer (score 0):

Check with database admin. They can check if anything is going on with the table. May be someone is performing something on the table in different session. Admin can kill the session. Then, you will be able to delete/truncate the table.