# I want to add a column in oracle table on button click

Tags: java, oracle, swing

```
ad.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String name = txtnm.getText();
            String cnm = Integer.toString(id)+name;
            try {
                System.out.print(cnm);

                st = con.createStatement();  // st is an object of Statement class
                int result = st.executeUpdate("alter table emp_att add ("+cnm+" varchar(30))"); //how to pass coloumn name in sql query

                if(result !=0)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Table Altered");
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something Went Wrong..");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Error : " + e);
            }
        }
    });
```

in above code i m try to do add column on button click but SQLException occur and give eroor as ORA-00904: : invalid identifier how to solve this problem

Comment: What is the value you're giving to `cnm`? AFIK you cannot have column name starting with number.

Comment: After add maybe there are no (). Refer here :http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/tables/alter_table.php

Comment: You should check the name of the column in database, for instance it might be surrendered by double quotes for example : "Youyou" instead of Youyou .

Comment: @Simze I got it what you say. .thnks..  bt another exception introduced like : ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified.. I m new in java can you please help me to fix this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORA-00904` tells you that name of a column is not valid. here are the rules:

- it can't be reserved oracle word;
- must begin with a letter;
- be less than or equal to thirty characters;
- consist only of alphanumeric and the special characters;

as your column name start's with a number but not letter, you get this error

Comment: Thnks @hahn ..i fix that problem but another exception introduced like ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified . can u please fix this exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842765/ora-00054-resource-busy-and-acquire-with-nowait-specified-or-timeout-expired