# Huge oracle insert statement gets stuck

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to add data from multiple XML files into my Oracle database. I'm receiving the data in my .NET C# application and I'm using Dapper as ORM.

Currently there are 13 XML files which need to be added into the database. I deserialized all of them and turned them into an `INSERT` query to add to my database.

Everything seems to be working fine, except after 31 minutes of trying to insert the data in the database, I noticed the following error:

> ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout
>   expired

After some searching I found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895078/2664414 but this seems **way** to hacky for something this "simple".
As for the details of the `INSERT` statement, I'm adding 3271 rows for the second `INSERT`. Here is a short snippet:

```
INSERT ALL 
   INTO S1589_XML_LineSection (ID, VALID_FROM_DATE, VALID_TO_DATE, LINE_ID, CHANNEL_NO, TENSION, NATURE, P70, C70, P400, C400, OPERATIONAL_IMPORTANCE, TECHNICAL_EQUIPMENT, OPERATIONALISATION, STANDARD_SPEED_DIR_1, STANDARD_SPEED_DIR_2, LAST_UPDATE_DATE) VALUES ('1','1996-06-02','2005-12-10','404','0','1','1','0','0','330','330','9','9','1','0','0','2010-06-04T04:54:51') 
   INTO S1589_XML_LineSection (ID, VALID_FROM_DATE, VALID_TO_DATE, LINE_ID, CHANNEL_NO, TENSION, NATURE, P70, C70, P400, C400, OPERATIONAL_IMPORTANCE, TECHNICAL_EQUIPMENT, OPERATIONALISATION, STANDARD_SPEED_DIR_1, STANDARD_SPEED_DIR_2, LAST_UPDATE_DATE) VALUES ('1','2005-12-11','2007-12-08','404','0','1','1','0','0','330','330','9','9','1','60','60','2010-06-04T04:54:51')
SELECT 1 FROM dual
```

I can perfectly add these lines individually, but when I try to add them all at once, it takes way too long.

**So, tips on either improving the query, or making sure I don't get the error (ORA-00054)?**

Comment: I would save the files as CSV and then load via sqlldr

Comment: Well first of all you need to know **what resource is locked**. A half-decent DBA should be able to run a query and explain what's occurring. Once you know the cause of the `ora-00054` error you can develop an informed strategy. That has to be better than asking us to guess.

Comment: I guess that your inserts aren't responsible for that, but - as if someone else locked one of those tables *in exclusive mode* (?) with the NOWAIT option.