# Oracle Store Procedure in Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created a store procedure in Oracle. Can anyone let me know if there is a procedure to execute this oracle Store Procedure from Azure Data Factory V2?

Answer (score 0):

1. You could try [preCopyScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle#oracle-as-a-sink-type) in copy activity.
2. You could try [custom activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please give a brief explaination on how to use the preCopyScript?

Comment: You could put any script in in the preCopyScript. It will be called before each copy. So I guess you could also put an execute stored procedure script in it.

Comment: I have given the execute stored procedure script of oracle in the Pre-copy script. The following is the error I am getting : error occurred at recursive SQL level 1\nORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired Error in parameter

Comment: Have you verified your script in Oracle client? This is what I find for this error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842765/ora-00054-resource-busy-and-acquire-with-nowait-specified-or-timeout-expired