# How to call Oracle stored procedure from azure data factory v2

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, self-hosting, azure-data-factory

My requirement is copy data from Oracle to SQL Server. Before copying from Oracle database, I need to update the Oracle table using procedure which has some logic.

How do I execute Oracle stored procedure from Azure datafactory?

I referred [to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51591123/oracle-store-procedure-in-azure-data-factory-v2)

if I use `EXECUTE PROC_NAME (PARAM);` in `preCopy` script it's failing with following error

```
Failure happened on 'Source' side. 
ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,
Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException
Message=ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]
[Oracle]ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector,
Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException
Message=ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]
[Oracle]ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement,Source=msora28.dll
```

Could anyone help on this?

Note: I am using self-hosted runtime environment for data factory
thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I used a Lookup Activity and a SELECT statement of DUAL TABLE. Due to the stored procedures can not be call from a statement SELECT. I created an oracle function and the function calls the stored procedure. The function returns a value and this value is received by the lookup activity.
When you define the function, you have to add the statement PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION. This is because Oracle does not allow to execute DML instructions with a SELECT statement by default. Then, you need to define that DML instructions in the Stored Procedure will be an autonomous transaction.

```
--Tabla
CREATE TABLE empleados(
   emp_id NUMBER(9),
   nombre VARCHAR2(100),
   CONSTRAINT empleados_pk PRIMARY KEY(emp_id),
);

create or replace procedure insert_empleado (numero in NUMBER, nombre in VARCHAR2) is
 begin
    INSERT INTO empleados (emp_id, nombre)
    Values(numero, nombre);
COMMIT;
end;

create or replace function funcinsert_empleado (numero in NUMBER, nombre in VARCHAR2)
return VARCHAR2 
is
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
begin
  insert_empleado (numero, nombre);
  return 'done';
end;
--statement in query of lookup
SELECT  funcinsert_empleado ('1', 'Roger Federer') 
FROM DUAL;
```

[Example lookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1qPC.png)

This is example in Spanish. https://dev.to/maritzag/ejecutar-un-stored-procedure-de-oracle-desde-data-factory-2jcp

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, `EXECUTE X(Y)` is a SQL*Plus-specific command shortcut for the PL/SQL statement `BEGIN X(Y); END;`. Since you are not using SQL*Plus, try the BEGIN/END syntax.

Answer (score -1):

**In case you only want to execute the DML query using the Azure Data Factory without procedure on oracle database  :-**

I have another solution where you can use the copy activity with the pre-copy feature of sink in-spite of lookup activity.

For this approach just follow the below steps :-

1. Keep both the source table and sink table as same ( Let say table A ) using the same linked service.
2. In sink use the pre-copy script feature and keep the DML (Insert/Update/Delete ) query that you want to perform over the table B.( This table is not necessary to be same as table A )
3. In case you want to avoid the copy of data to same table you can select query option in the source part and provide a where clause which is not going to satisfy and hence no copy of data will happen .
   or you can create a table temp with one column and one row .
   I have tested both the options and it works ... good part of above solution is you can avoid the procedure or function creation and maintenance .