# Execute a stored procedure in Oracle from Azure Data Factory v2

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a list of copy activities that are dynamically triggered in my ADF pipeline parallelly to load data from Azure SQL to Oracle 9i Database. I have a requirement to update a Status Table on Oracle if all my loads are completed successfully.

I tried multiple approaches provided in this community with no luck. Just wondering if I am missing anything. Any pointers please?

**Approach 1 :**
Create a SP on Oracle :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AZ.UPDATE_LOOKUP_TEST AS
BEGIN
update AZ.STATUS_DIM set Status='Completed' where Database ='NLM';
COMMIT;
END;
```

ADF:
Lookup Activty
[image]

Error details
Error code  2100
Failure type
User configuration issue
Details
ErrorCode=InvalidParameter,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The value of the property 'columns' is invalid: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: columns'.,Source=,''Type=System.ArgumentNullException,Message=Value cannot be null. Parameter name: columns,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'

**Approach 2 :**

Query in Lookup Activity :
EXECUTE AZURE45.UPDATE_LOOKUP_TEST;

Error :

Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement,Source=msora28.dll,'

**Approach 3:**
Directly provide the update statement in the Query

Query : update AZ.STATUS_DIM set Status='Completed' where Database ='NLM';

Error :

ErrorCode=InvalidParameter,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The value of the property 'columns' is invalid: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: columns'.,Source=,''Type=System.ArgumentNullException,Message=Value cannot be null. Parameter name: columns,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'

How do I execute Oracle stored procedure from Azure datafactory?

Comment: Just from error message, does the stored procedure should have the parameter "columns"?

Comment: @LeonYue, I don't think so, I compiled and executed the stored procedure on Oracle and it works fine with no issues and the row gets updated.

Comment: The error _The value of the property 'columns' is invalid: 'Value cannot be null_ means to me that your stored proc needs to return a rowset with at least one column. The error is ADF not seeing any columns being returned from your proc. Try adding `SELECT 1 MyCol FROM DUAL;` to the end of your proc

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid. I've tried a similar approach as per [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63204428/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedure-from-azure-data-factory-v2) and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. Ended up being an issue with the ODBC driver that ADF is using. It requires a particular syntax.

The syntax I successfully used was:

```
CALL NAMEOFPACKAGE_PKG.NameOfFuntion()
```

which I called from a Script Activity