# Invoking Oracle stored procedure in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, oracle-adf, on-premises-instances

I have a requirement to invoke an Oracle stored procedure in Azure Data Factory pipeline and I tried calling my stored procedure in Oracle function and invoked that function in my pipeline but it is not working.

Is there any way to invoke an Oracle stored procedure in an Azure Data Factory pipeline?

Comment: Duplicate of existing SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63204428/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedure-from-azure-data-factory-v2).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
With stored_procedure as (select function(pass-parameter) as alias from dual) 
select * from stored_procedure schema_name.table_name;
```