# DB table getting lock after run the program

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, transactions, ora-00054

I need to insert data to `TBL_LOAN_DETAILS` table. when calling the `LoanDetails()` method those data need to insert to the table, In `TBL_LOAN_DETAILS` `ID` is auto incrementing.  After insertion data to the `TBL_LOAN_DETAILS` I need to take that record `ID` to pass as a prameter another method called `CribProcess()` within  `LoanDetails()`. In this after some calculation/ logic again I need to update some column of `TBL_LOAN_DETAILS`. to  achieve that I used following code. (I'm unable to paste complete code here,beacause stackoverflow blocked it,so I use pastebin) . I put a brakepoint to this line                                 `lAEntities.TBL_LOAN_DETAILS.Add(tBlLoanDetails);` programe not not running after this line.`lAEntities.SaveChanges();`

Part of my code: please check my full code using link.

```
public LoanDetailEntityResponse LoanDetails(string custId, string facilityType, string applyedDate, string currency,string RequiredLoanAmount,string RepaymentPeriod,
                                            string NIC,string CustName,string DateofBirth, string CommunicationAddress,string MobileNumber,string LoanPurpose,string Occupation,string NetIncome,string Expenses,string Education_qualification,
                                            string TypeOfEmployment,string GE_Emp_Category,string Emp_Period,string GE_Position,string PE_Existence, string PE_Position,string SE_Experience,string SE_Business_Nature, string ValueOfAssets,
                                            string SE_Bus_RegNoo_Availability, string SE_Maintain_Financial_Recode, List<LandPropertyAsset> AssetLandList, List<VehicleAsset> AssetVehicleList)
{

    var refNo = string.Empty;
    var response = new LoanDetailEntityResponse();

        var lAEntities = new LAEntities();
        DateTime appDate;
        DateTime DOB;
        using (var transaction = lAEntities.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
                if (DateTime.TryParse(applyedDate, out appDate))
                 {
                    applyedDate = appDate.ToShortDateString();
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(DateofBirth, out DOB))
                    {
                        DateofBirth = DOB.ToShortDateString();

                         refNo = Common.GetSerialSequence("LOANREFERENCENO", transaction);

                        string approvalStatus = "";
                        int approvalId = 1;
                        decimal loanId = 0;

                        var tBlLoanDetails = new TBL_LOAN_DETAILS
                        {
                            CUSTID = custId,
                            REFNO = refNo,
                            FACILITY_TYPE = facilityType,
                            APPLIED_DATE = applyedDate,
                            CURRENCY = currency,
                            REQLOANAMOUNT = Convert.ToDecimal(RequiredLoanAmount),
                            REPAYMENTPERIOD = RepaymentPeriod,
                            NIC = NIC,
                            CUSTNAME = CustName,
                            DATEOFBIRTH = DateofBirth,
                            COMMUNICATIONADDRESS = CommunicationAddress,
                            MOBILENUMBER = MobileNumber,
                            PURPOSEOFLOAN = LoanPurpose,
                            OCCUPATION = Occupation,
                            NETINCOME = Convert.ToDecimal(NetIncome),
                            EXPENSES = Convert.ToDecimal(Expenses),
                            EDUCATION_QUALIFICATION = Education_qualification,
                            TYPEOFEMPLOYMENT = TypeOfEmployment,
                            GE_EMP_CATEGORY = Convert.ToInt32(GE_Emp_Category),
                            EMP_PERIOD = Convert.ToInt32(Emp_Period),
                            GE_POSITION = Convert.ToInt32(GE_Position),
                            PE_EXISTENCE = Convert.ToInt32(PE_Existence),
                            PE_POSITION = Convert.ToInt32(PE_Position),
                            SE_EXPERIENCE = Convert.ToInt32(SE_Experience),
                            SE_BUS_NATURE = Convert.ToInt32(SE_Business_Nature),
                            SE_BUS_REGNNO_AVAILABILITY = SE_Bus_RegNoo_Availability,
                            SE_MAINTAAIN_FINANTIAL_RECORD = SE_Maintain_Financial_Recode,
                            EMP_VALUEOFASSETS = Convert.ToInt32(ValueOfAssets),
                            LOAN_STATUS_ID = approvalId,
                            REPAYMENTSCORE = 0,
                            PROPOSED_LOAN_FACI_INSTA = 0,
                            EXSISTING_LOAN_FACI_INSTA = 0,
                            ODINTEREST = 0,
                            CREDITCARD = 0,
                            SURPLUS = 0,
                            LOAN_STATUS_DES = "",
                            ISACTIVE = 1,
                            CREATEDBY = "System",
                            CREATEDDATETIME = DateTime.Now,
                            MODIFIEDBY = "System",
                            MODIFIEDDATETIME = DateTime.Now
                        };
                        lAEntities.TBL_LOAN_DETAILS.Add(tBlLoanDetails);
                        lAEntities.SaveChanges();
                        //transaction.Commit();                         

                        var loanDetail = lAEntities.TBL_LOAN_DETAILS.FirstOrDefault(x => x.REFNO.Equals(refNo) && x.ISACTIVE == 1);
                        if (loanDetail != null)
                        {
                            loanId = loanDetail.ID;


                            // Call Crib process
                            AppSettingsReader configReader = new AppSettingsReader();
                            var chromeDriverUrl = (string)configReader.GetValue("ChromeDriverUrl", typeof(string));
                            var navigateUrl = (string)configReader.GetValue("CRIBNavigateUrl", typeof(string));
                            var userName = "";
                            var password = "";
                            CribAutoProcess ca = new CribAutoProcess();
                            int facilityID = int.Parse(loanId.ToString());
                            ca.CribProcess(navigateUrl, userName, password, facilityID, CustName, NIC, "Testing");

                        }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

[Full Code here](https://pastebin.com/2RRL7jrR)

after run the programe, `TBL_LOAN_DETAILS` table getting lock, which means, when I trying to drop table using oracle sql developer this oracle error message showing.

> ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout
>   expired

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using transactions, you need to either perform a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`. If you don't, the error you're currently experiencing will occur because the transaction is still using the record regardless if you used the `using` keyword and it was disposed.

What you can do to remove the lock is restart the service running oracle or kill the process in oracle holding the lock. Afterwards, oracle will perform its own `ROLLBACK` process and the lock will be gone.

Comment: Sir what should I need to do now,please give me a sample code

Comment: The reason why you encountered the problem is because you commented out `//transaction.Commit();`. Remove the comment and you should not encounter this problem anymore but the locked rows will still be locked in the oracle database. You will need to kill the process/session. See [ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION Tips](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_alter_system_kill_session.htm).

Comment: Sir I uncomment that line, but code not execute after this line `lAEntities.SaveChanges();` and no any exception occurr. I kill the sessions also. please check my complete code and give me a solution

Comment: What does `Common.GetSerialSequence("LOANREFERENCENO", transaction);` do? Can you share the code too? Also to kill the correct blocking session see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21675358/6138713).